# os.path.getsize gives wrong size of .dll file in windows 10

Tags: python, file, windows-10

Python 3.6.0, Windows 10 (64 bit)

```
import os
path = r'C:\Windows\System32\AdvancedInstallers\cmiv2.dll'
print(os.path.getsize(path))
```

this code gives output of `2193248` but when I see the properties of this file it show `3252576`. It's not size on disk property. I'm talking about actual size.

[image: file properties]

I am expecting python program to print `3252576`.

Comment: Can you print the output of `with open(path) as f: print(len(f.read()))`?

Comment: Also, is the file being actively downloaded while you run these tests by any chance?

Comment: What is the output of `print(os.stat(path).st_size)`

Comment: @MadPhysicist, http://pasteboard.co/AvK8zHOJj.png

http://pasteboard.co/AvNeELG15.png

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, `print(os.stat(path).st_size)` gives `2193248`

Comment: Please edit your question with the additional info. I can't see the images properly on mobile

Comment: Also, my mistake, `open(path)` should be `open(path, 'rb')`

Comment: @MadPhysicist, I tried this on other files. It works fine. I think only this file have issue. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may have to do with [NTFS alternate data streams](http://techgenix.com/alternate_data_streams/). Though the article states that the presence of ADS in a file doesn't affect its size, things may have changed since the article was written (back in 2004) and Windows 10's property dialog may well account for all ADSs in a file, while python doesn't.

A [more recent blog post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2013/03/24/alternate-data-streams-in-ntfs/) explains how to examine the data streams of a file using PowerShell utilities:

```
Get-item -Path C:\Windows\System32\AdvancedInstallers\cmiv2.dll -stream *
```

If my hypothesis is correct then the output should look something like the following:

```
   FileName: C:\Windows\System32\AdvancedInstallers\cmiv2.dll

Stream                  Length
------                  ------
:$DATA                  2193248
SomethingElse           1059328
```

(or *SomethingElse* may actually consist of several smaller streams with sizes adding up to 1059328).

Comment: @MaulikGangani Does the problem happen for some other files too?

Comment: I tried with other files, It works fine. I think this file have some issue for python. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: pls change your anser @Leon and reflect this :)

Comment: @MaulikGangani I am puzzled at why you accepted this answer if it doesn't answer your question.

Comment: actually I was not intrested in cmiv2.dll's size. I thought getsize() is not working for my (whole) system. Your comment helped me with that so...